# undefined is not a function (near '...ManageWallpaper.setWallpaper...')

Tags: javascript

I'm working on wallpaper app in react native and iget this problem and i don't know why i get it. I properly did installation of module...
I get error when i use ManageWallpaper node module.
Here is code:

```
 _callback = res => {
    console.log('Response: ', res);
  };

  _setWallpaper = () => {
    console.log(images[brc]);
    ManageWallpaper.setWallpaper(
      {
        uri:
          'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/76/5e/1d/765e1dc8cb1cc115fb3b0b39a895fdeb.jpg',
      },
      this._callback,
      ManageWallpaper.TYPE.HOME,
    );
  };
  <View style={styles.barContainer}>{barArray}</View>
  <View style={{zIndex: 2, position:'absolute', bottom: 0}}>
  <Button title="Set as Wallpaper" color="blue" onPress={_setWallpaper}/>
```

Comment: Did you forget to import `ManageWallpaper` from somewhere?

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle i imported it 
import * as  ManageWallpaper from 'react-native-manage-wallpaper';